# Android device emulator fails due to bad permissions Linux

Tags: android, linux, permissions, android-emulator

I am trying to install flutter without android-studio, currently the `flutter doctor` gives all ticks except for android studio and connected devices as per [this guide](https://dev.to/jay_js/setting-up-flutter-without-android-studio-olo). I created an emulator through `avdmanager`, and if I run it with `flutter emulators --launch pixel` it gets stuck on the loading screen and then becomes unresponsive. To get some more information I can run it with `${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/emulator -avd pixel`, this does the same thing but returns the following debug information:

```
emulator: WARNING: IniFile.cpp:235: Failed to open .ini file /home/cameron/.android/avd/pixel.avd/hardware-qemu.ini for writing.
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=/home/cameron/.android/avd/pixel.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576: Could not open '/home/cameron/.android/avd/pixel.avd/cache.img.qcow2': Permission denied
Killed
```

Now since it seems to be a permissions issue, I can run the same command with sudo and it is able to start up the emulator but when I use the virtual power button to start the phone os it crashes with:

```
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5]
E0619 23:22:33.309764951   29720 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1592572953.309674506","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
 - Click "OK"

[29707:29707:0619/232311.505803:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

I've tried to common response I found on the internet which is to use adduser on kvm but this didn't change anything. Some windows users have suggested marking certain files as writable but since I don't know which I'm very apprehensive. PS I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try

> flutter clean

and then restart your flutter

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this doesn't do anything since I don't have a flutter project.

Comment: CameronBell If your project has nothing to do with flutter then first thing you should do is remove the flutter tag from your question.

Comment: Ok I've removed that tag